# How do I make a Dataframe of columns and unique values stacked?

Tags: pandas, data-manipulation

I have a large data frame that I would like to develop a summation table from.  In other words, column 1 would be the columns of the first data frame, column 2 would be each unique value of each column and column three thru ... would be a summation of different variables I choose.  Like the below:

```
Variable   Level   Summed_Column
```

Here is some sample code:

```
data = {"name": ['bob', 'john', 'mary', 'timmy']
       , "age": [32, 32, 29, 28]
       , "location": ['philly', 'philly', 'philly', 'ny']
       , "amt": [100, 2000, 300, 40]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.head()
```

So the output in the above example would be as follows:

```
Variable     Level     Summed_Column
Name         Bob       100
Name         john      2000
Name         Mary      300
Name         timmy     40
age          32        2100
age          29        300
age          29        40
location     philly    2400
location     ny        40
```

I'm not even sure where to start.  The actual dataframe has 32 columns in which 4 will be summed and 28 put into the `variable` and `Level` format.

Comment: Have you looked into `pd.melt`? Not 100% sure but it could be of use here

Comment: Thanks @Datanovice.  I've tried `pd.melt` but it seems to duplicate values.  I need unique values for each variable and a summation of the other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop for this and concatenation, you can do this in one go by combining `melt` with `groupby` and using the `agg` method:

```
final = df.melt(value_vars=['name', 'age', 'location'], id_vars='amt')\
          .groupby(['variable', 'value']).agg({'amt':'sum'})\
          .reset_index()
```

Which yields:

```
print(final)
   variable   value   amt
0       age      28    40
1       age      29   300
2       age      32  2100
3  location      ny    40
4  location  philly  2400
5      name     bob   100
6      name    john  2000
7      name    mary   300
8      name   timmy    40
```

Comment: yeah that's a lot cleaner.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

ok @Datanovice.  I figured out how to do this using a for loop w/ `pd.melt`.

```
id = ['name', 'age', 'location']

final = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['variable', 'value', 'amt'])

for i in id:
    table = df.groupby(i).agg({'amt':'sum'}).reset_index()
    table2 = pd.melt(table, value_vars = i, id_vars = ['amt'])
    final = pd.concat([final, table2])

print(final)
```